# If statement to show toast or continue to next activity

Tags: java, android

Not getting any errors im just stumped on this friggin if statement. I want the if statement to basically say if a check box is not checked and 3 EditTexts are empty then print a toast. Otherwise dont print the toast and continue to the next activity. First I turn the value of the checkbox into either t/f for true/false then execute my if statements as the following.

```
CheckBox noPtD1 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.noPTD1);
String noPt_D1 = "f";
if (noPtD1.isChecked()) {
    noPt_D1 = "t";
}



if (noPt_D1.equals("f") && day1_inst.equals("") || day1_uniform.equals("") ||
day1_location.equals(""))
{
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please Enter All Data Or Select the NO PT THIS DAY
    checkbox!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
if(noPt_D1.equals("t") || !day1_inst.equals("") && !day1_uniform.equals("") &&
!day1_location.equals(""))
{
    //PASS VARIABLES WITH INTENT
    Intent intent = new Intent (OneWeekPlan_Start_Btn.this, Week1Day2.class);

    //PASS VARIABLES FOR DAY 1
    intent.putExtra("noPt_D1", noPt_D1);
    intent.putExtra("day1_inst", day1_inst);
    intent.putExtra("day1_uniform", day1_uniform);
    intent.putExtra("day1_location", day1_location);
    intent.putExtra("d1hours", d1hours);
    intent.putExtra("d1min", d1min);
    intent.putExtra("d1x1", d1x1);
    intent.putExtra("d1x2", d1x2);
    intent.putExtra("d1x3", d1x3);
    intent.putExtra("d1x4", d1x4);              
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

This is working except for then I check the checkbox and and start the next activity with a button the next activity pops up like it is supposed to but the toast still appears. What did I mess up?

I got it I posted my answer below. But to rephrase exactly what my intent was:

If the user DOES NOT check the checkbox and leaves all 3 inputtexts blank show the toast and dont continue to next activity.

If the user DOES check the checkbox then DONT show the toast and continue to next activity.

Comment: Try to change this value in Toast build : Toast.LENGTH_LONG to Toast.LENGTH_SHORT.

Comment: You mean u need value in atleast 1 edit text?

Comment: why first condition is checking OR Condition and second condition AND.day1_inst how you declare these variable in your code.

Comment: what you exactly want?.. if noPt_D1=false then all 3 edittexts should be filled and if noPt_D1=true then no need to check for 3 edittexts? is it correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

also try this. and its better to avoid including special characters for ur class name

```
if ("f".equals(noPt_D1) && "".equals(day1_inst) || "".equals(day1_uniform) ||
    "".equals(day1_location))
    {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please Enter All Data Or Select the NO PT THIS DAY
        checkbox!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    if("t".equals(noPt_D1) || !"".equals(day1_inst) && !"".equals(day1_uniform) &&
    !"".equals(day1_location))
    {
        //PASS VARIABLES WITH INTENT
        Intent intent = new Intent (OneWeekPlan_Start_Btn.this, Week1Day2.class);

        //PASS VARIABLES FOR DAY 1
        intent.putExtra("noPt_D1", noPt_D1);
        intent.putExtra("day1_inst", day1_inst);
        intent.putExtra("day1_uniform", day1_uniform);
        intent.putExtra("day1_location", day1_location);
        intent.putExtra("d1hours", d1hours);
        intent.putExtra("d1min", d1min);
        intent.putExtra("d1x1", d1x1);
        intent.putExtra("d1x2", d1x2);
        intent.putExtra("d1x3", d1x3);
        intent.putExtra("d1x4", d1x4);              
        startActivity(intent);
    }
```

Comment: thats still showing the toast when i hit the button

Comment: is toast is always visible?. and `Toast.LENGTH_LONG` takes some time to invisible abt 5-10 seconds.

Answer (score 3):

Use brackets inside if statement

```
if (noPt_D1.equals("f") && (day1_inst.equals("") || day1_uniform.equals("") ||
day1_location.equals("")))
{

}
if(noPt_D1.equals("t") || (!day1_inst.equals("") && !day1_uniform.equals("") &&
!day1_location.equals("")))
{

}
```

Answer (score 3):

You are making minor mistake in condition **PLUS** you need to use if - else block instead of 2 if blocks

```
//surround all && conditions inside separate braces
if (noPt_D1.equals("f") && (day1_inst.equals("") || day1_uniform.equals("") ||
day1_location.equals("")))
{
    //show toast
}
else if(noPt_D1.equals("t") || (!day1_inst.equals("") && !day1_uniform.equals("") &&
!day1_location.equals("")))
{
    //start activity
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

Try to check `EditText` values via `length()` of String value. Secondly put `&&` operator in if statement because you said in your question: `if a check box is not checked and 3 EditTexts are empty then print a toast. Otherwise dont print the toast and continue to the next activity.`

```
if (noPt_D1.equals("f") && day1_inst.trim().length() == 0 && day1_uniform.trim().length() == 0 &&
                          day1_location.trim().length() == 0)
{
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please Enter All Data", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
else
{
     Intent intent = new Intent (OneWeekPlan_Start_Btn.this, Week1Day2.class);

     intent.putExtra("noPt_D1", noPt_D1);
     intent.putExtra("day1_inst", day1_inst);
     intent.putExtra("day1_uniform", day1_uniform);
     intent.putExtra("day1_location", day1_location);
     intent.putExtra("d1hours", d1hours);
     intent.putExtra("d1min", d1min);
     intent.putExtra("d1x1", d1x1);
     intent.putExtra("d1x2", d1x2);
     intent.putExtra("d1x3", d1x3);
     intent.putExtra("d1x4", d1x4);              
     startActivity(intent);
}
```

**EDIT:**

Make sure you should declare your Strings which I am assuming are:

```
String day1_inst = your_editText_inst.getText().toString();
String day1_uniform = your_editText_uniform.getText().toString();
String day1_location = your_editText_location.getText().toString();
String noPt_D1 = "f";
if(your_check_box.isChecked())
{
    noPt_D1 = "t"; 
}
else
{
    noPt_D1 = "f"; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using an OnCheckedChangeListener Listener, like whats shown below :

```
CheckBox noPtD1 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.noPTD1);
String noPt_D1 = "f";
noPtD1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                if (isChecked) {
                    noPt_D1 = "t";
                } else {
                    noPt_D1 = "f";
                }
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace getApplicationContext() with this if you are in activity. getActivity() if you're in fragment.

Answer (score 1):

Just figured it out thanks to M S Gadag =)

Basically I took the if statements and put the startActivity if statement on top. Then I added a variable to show that that statement had already been executed. Then I used that variable to start another if statement to decide whether or not to show the toast.

```
int showToast = 0;

if("t".equals(noPt_D1) || !"".equals(day1_inst) && !"".equals(day1_uniform) &&
!"".equals(day1_location))
{
    //PASS VARIABLES WITH INTENT
    Intent intent = new Intent (OneWeekPlan_Start_Btn.this, Week1Day2.class);

    //PASS VARIABLES FOR DAY 1
    intent.putExtra("noPt_D1", noPt_D1);
    intent.putExtra("day1_inst", day1_inst);
    intent.putExtra("day1_uniform", day1_uniform);
    intent.putExtra("day1_location", day1_location);
    intent.putExtra("d1hours", d1hours);
    intent.putExtra("d1min", d1min);
    intent.putExtra("d1x1", d1x1);
    intent.putExtra("d1x2", d1x2);
    intent.putExtra("d1x3", d1x3);
    intent.putExtra("d1x4", d1x4);              
    startActivity(intent);

    showToast = 1;
}       

if ("f".equals(noPt_D1) && "".equals(day1_inst) || "".equals(day1_uniform) ||
"".equals(day1_location))
{
    if (showToast !=1)
    {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please Enter All Data Or Select the NO PT THIS
        DAY checkbox!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

Comment: welcome n if my answer helped u pls up it or accept it as ans buddy.. :)